# Raising exception if error does not occur

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, exit, try-except

I am working with selenium webdriver in python3. When the driver reaches a certain page and if a certain class element with class `shiftUp` is present, I want to print response and stop execution at that point. Currently, I am doing this as follows:

```py
flag = 0
try:
    error_source_file = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shiftUp")
    flag = 1
except:
    pass
if flag:
    print("RESPONSE")
    sys.exit()
```

I want a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) clause:

```
try:
    error_source_file = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shiftUp")
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
else:
    print("RESPONSE")
    sys.exit()
```

It gets triggered for the cases that don't raise an error: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions:

> The `try … except` statement has an optional *else clause*, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

and

> The use of the `else` clause is better than adding additional code to the `try` clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the `try … except` statement.

I would recommend catching only `NoSuchElementException` for a similar reason: you don't want to trap errors you don't intend to.

Answer (score -1):

Why not:

```
try:
    error_source_file = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shiftUp")
    print("RESPONSE")
    sys.exit()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

The lines after `error_source_file` won't be executed if the `find_element` method raises an exception.

> NB: Consider precising the type of the exception you want to catch (ex: `except IndexError:`), or you could silent errors, which is really bad.

Comment: problem with it is that sys.exit() throws exception in try block. So, it ultimately goes to except block.

Comment: @olinox. This way is specifically not recommended in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right, but there still is no problem with that solution (even if yours is better)